# Problems with data types

Tags: c#, ms-access, parameters, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm trying to insert a new record into a table with this fields, but it gaves me "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"... i've already checked the types, bit it always fails...

I don't know if the size of the field are correct, some help?

```
    public static void InsertCommand(Veicolo v, string connString)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand
            {
                CommandText = "INSERT INTO Veicoli VALUES ('@targa', @automoto,'@marca', '@modello', @cilindrata, @potenzakw," +
                "@immatricolazione,@usato,@kmzero,@kmpercorsi,'@colore',@prezzo,'@imagepath','@caratteristica');",
                Connection=connection
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@targa",OleDbType.VarChar,255).Value= v.Targa;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@automoto",OleDbType.Boolean,2).Value = (v is Auto);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@marca", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = v.Marca;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@modello", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = v.Modello;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cilindrata", OleDbType.Integer, 32).Value = v.Cilindrata;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@potenzakw", OleDbType.Double, 32).Value = v.PotenzaKw;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@immatricolazione", OleDbType.DBDate, 32).Value = v.Immatricolazione;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@usato", OleDbType.Boolean, 2).Value = v.IsUsato;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@kmzero", OleDbType.Boolean, 2).Value = v.IsKmZero;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@kmpercorsi", OleDbType.Integer, 32).Value = v.KmPercorsi; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@colore", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = v.Colore;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prezzo", OleDbType.Double, 32).Value = v.Prezzo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagepath", OleDbType.VarChar, 255 ).Value = v.ImagePath;
            string c = (v is Auto ? (v as Auto).NumeroAirBag.ToString() : (v as Moto).MarcaSella);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@caratteristica", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value =c;
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    //ERROR data type mismatch in criteria expression
        }
    }

    public static string createTableVeicoliSqlString =
        $"CREATE TABLE Veicoli (" +
            $"Targa varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
            $"AutoMoto boolean," +
            $"Marca varchar(255)," +
            $"Modello varchar(255)," +
            $"Cilindrata int," +
            $"PotenzaKw double," +
            $"Immatricolazione datetime," +
            $"Usato boolean," +
            $"KmZero boolean," +
            $"KmPercorsi int," +
            $"Colore varchar(255)," +
            $"Prezzo double," +
            $"ImagePath varchar(255)," +
            $"Caratteristica varchar(255)" +
            $");";
```

Comment: For debug, you can remove half of the insert values/column and see if you trigger the error. It's a little of messy edit but it could help  indentifying  the issue

Comment: @Jombo. Drag and Drop brought up a great debugging technique where you remove half of the things that could be going wrong so you can then go, it works now, or it still doesn't work. Now you have narrowed the problem's scope by half. Now half the half that didn't work and repeat until you find your problem line.

Comment: Parameters placeholders should not be enclosed in single quotes. In that way they becomes literal strings and the db tries to insert that string instead of the parameter value

Comment: Also you should really specify the columns you are inserting into `INSERT INTO Veicoli(Targa, AutoMoto,....)` to make sure the parameters will match up.  Otherwise you're relying on the order of the column in the DB

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple reasons for this outside of the ones you have ruled out:

1. One of your properties in "Veicolo v" is null and the db field is non nullable.
2. Your insertion script missed out another non nullable field that is not in your code.

Comment: Actually if a column is nullable and the value is null you have to translate it to `DBNull.Value` to get it to work